How do you reference Amazon - the company?
How do you reference Amazon - the company - in a bibliography?
The guides online have examples for citing a product on Amazon, but how do you cite the company itself?

Do you mean a publication authored by "Amazon"? Different style guides will have different ideas, with the APA Publication Manual IMO being on the most breathtakingly anal-retentively precise end of the spectrum. If you are told to use a specific style guide, look there; if not, I would recommend you use some reasonable way of citing.

Think of this this way: you don't cite Maarten Buis, but some article written by me. It is the same way with Amazon; you don't cite Amazon, but some technical report, press release, or something else written by that company.

I'm trying to understand how to reference an entire company, for example when making an analogy such as "the Amazon of the Victorian era," - how do you cite Amazon?

This looks a lot like an "XY problem". Why do you think you need to cite Amazon the company?

@ina Why would you need to cite Amazon for that statement? It's not like Amazon made that claim.

It’s Amazon.com, Inc.
